# How do I prove sets are injective or surjective?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, multisets

Let  be the set of all lists (of any length) whose entries are only 0’s and 1’s, and let  be the set
of nonnegative integers. Define a function :  →  as follows: for any list  in ,
() = the number of 1’s in .

(a) Is  one-to-one? Prove or give a counterexample.

(b) Is  onto? Prove or give a counterexample.

I'm mostly confused as to what set  would actually look like. I see it as being something like  = {1,0,1,0,1,0...}. In which case is it true that  can't be one-to-one because any 0 or a 1 from  would map directly to only a 0 or 1 in ? Also could it be onto even both of these are infinite sets?

Comment: The elements of $S$ are (presumably finite) lists of $0$'s and $1$'s. Among the elements in $S$ are $(0), (1), (0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1), (0,0,0), (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,1,1)$,... Are there two finite lists of $0$'s and $1$'s which are distinct but have the same number of $1$'s? Can you find a finite list of $0$'s and $1$'s which have a given number of $1$'s?

Comment: You seem a bit confused as to the definitions.  For one, injectivity and surjectivity are properties of functions, not sets, so it doesn't make sense to ask whether a set $S$ is injective or surjective as in your title (unless $S$ happens to be a function.)

Comment: Also, remember that $S$ is a set of lists, not any particular list.  So you would not have $S = \{1,0,1,0,1,\ldots\}$.  You'd have $S = \{ (0), (1), (0,0), (0,1), ... \}$, the set of all binary lists, as Hayden says above.

Comment: $f$ is a function that inputs a list of ones and zeros and outputs a number: the number of ones.  So if $f$ is one-to-one, that means that no two different lists of zeroes and ones can map to the same number, i.e., no two different lists have the same number of ones. Is that true?

Comment: It appears that multiple lists have the same number of ones and zeros, for instance both lists can have (0,0), (1,0), (1,1) etc. so therefore it is not one-to-one?

Comment: I also know that to prove a function is onto, that I have to prove that for all $y\in T$ there exists an $x\in S$ such that $f(S)=T$. I get how to do this with equations, I just don't know how to begin with lists of numbers.

Comment: They don't have to have the same number of $0$s (although they could) to have the same output; just the same number of $1$s.  So $f((1,1)) = 2; f((1,1,0)) =2; f((1,0,1))=2; f(0,1,1)=2; f((0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)) = 2$.

Comment: What is $f((\underbrace{1,1,1,1,.......,1}_{\text{a list of }n\text{ ones}}))$?

Comment: So is the $f(s)$ actually $T$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S$ is a set of lists.  So if *one* list is something like $(0,0,1,1,0)$, (I'll write list between parenthesis for notation), then $S$ is the set of all of these.

$S=\{(0),(0,0), (0,1),(1,0),(1,1),(0,0,0),(0,0,1),.... \}$

$T$ meanwhile is just $\mathbb N\cup \{0\}$.

And $F:S\to T$ by "counting the $1$".  So $F((0,0,1,1,0)) = 2$ and $F((1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0)) = 6$ for example.

> In which case is it true that  can't be one-to-one because any 0 or a 1 from  would map directly to only a 0 or 1 in ?

It's not the $0$s and the $1$s that are being mapped from.  It is the *lists* of $0$s and $1$s that are being mapped from.

And a function from a set $A$ to a different set $B$ don't have to map the same type of elements.  Consider $A = \{\text{animals}\}$ and $B=\{\text{food\}}$ and $f:A\to B$ via $f(x)=$ what $x$ eats.  Then $f(\text{horse})=\text{hay}$ even though hay is not an animal.  So $f((1,1,0)) = 2$ which is neither $0$ nor $1$.

> Also could it be onto even both of these are infinite sets?

The sets are infinite and you can have onto functions to infinite sets.

....

Now is $F$ one-to-one and is it onto.

Below are HUGE hints if you just put that question into simple words that make the answer UTTERLY obvious.  Don't read it unless you are absolutely stuck:

One-to-one:

> $F$ is one-to-one means the only time two lists $j,k$ have $F(j)=F(k)$ is if $j=k$.  In other words, the only time two lists have the same number of $1$s is when they are the lists are the same.  Is that true?  If two lists have the same number of $1$s, do that mean the two lists are the same?

Onto:

> $F$ is onto if for ever non-negative number there is a list with that many $1$s.  Is there? Can you think of a number for which there is *not* a list with that many $1$s?

Comment: So if I have a list of numbers, say $S=\{1,1,1,1\}$ and another list $T=\{2,3,4,5\}$ and $f:S\to T$, does that mean that this can't be one-to-one because there are 4 ones in set $S$, therefore meaning that the same number is mapping to the set $T$?

Comment: Also does this mean that the above list would be considered onto because you could possibly map each element from list $T$ to each element in list $S$?

Comment: List and sets are different things.  $S$ and $T$ above are *NOT* lists. Functions map the *elements* of sets to the elements of another set.  They do not map the elements of *lists*.  *FUNCTIONS* are one-to-one and onto.  Saying a set or a list is one-to-one or onto does not make any sense.

Comment: A *list* is a string of elements:  $0$ is a list, $1$ is a list $00;01;10;11$ are four more lists $000; 001;010;011;100$ are five more lists.  A *SET* is a collection of *elements*.  $S$ is a COLLECTION of whose **elements** are lists.  $S = \{0;1;00;01;10;11;000;001;010;011;100; ...etc.\}$.  When $F: S \to \mathbb N\cup\{0\}$ it is the *STRINGS* that are individually being mapped.  $F:011010\mapsto 3$.  The individual $0$s and $1$s that *make up* the strings have nothing to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

The set of lists is the set $\lbrace(0),(1),(0,1),(1,0),(0,0,1),...\rbrace$. Because $(1)$ and $(1,0)$ have the same number of $1$s the function is not 1-1 (injective). Because the set contains the list $(1,1,...,1,0)$ with $n$ $1$s (noting $n$ may be zero), there is at least one list for each number, so the function is onto (surjective).